# Setting Selector for InfoWindow

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've been using the Android GoogleMapApi and to my annoyance found that I couldn't set a drawable for the selector on an InfoWindow. I was wondering if there was an XML attribute like on a ListView or a workaround.

```
class InfoAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter
{

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker m) {
        View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mapsight, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mapsighttext);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.smallmappic);
        JSONObject j = locList.get(Integer.parseInt(m.getSnippet())).j;
        int drawable = 0;
        try {
            drawable = getResources().getIdentifier(Utils.removeFileType(j.getString("bigpic")).toLowerCase(), "drawable", getPackageName());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (drawable != 0) iv.setImageResource(drawable);
        else
        {

        }
        tv.setText(m.getTitle());
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker m) {
        return null;
    }

}
...
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoAdapter());
```

Thank you for any help possible

Comment: I was just wondering if it's possible, I'm just using a custom InfoWindow and I was hoping a user could click on it and start an activity and instead of turning blue it would turn another color

Comment: Then post your code, what I have write first, just read first